# Ввод условия java

Tags: java

Такая проблема, допустим я создал массив , в котором 3 объекта( к примеру : собака, кот, попугай)
Как мне задать условие, что, человеку нужно ввести животное, и , если он вместо "собака" вводит "шар, телефон или другой набор букв, не соответствующий набору массива" ему выдается ошибка, а если ввел правильно, то код продолжается. Если бы нужно было выбрать переменную или что-то вроде этого , я бы просто использовал бы if/else , а вот с текстом у меня проблема. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: ваш вопрос непонятен. Что за объекты в массиве? Это классы или экземпляры или строки? И почему массив? У вас есть какой то уже код?

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время. Есть массив string[] pets= {"собака", "кот","попугай"}; После человеку надо ввести любое, из данных, животное. я использовал scanner:         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                                             String b = in.nextLine(); .Мне надо, чтобы, если человек вместо животного ввел другое слово/набор букв, ему выводилась ошибка, а если он ввел правильно, то код продолжается

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен цикл. Также я заменил массив на HashSet, так как HashSet специально предназначен для хранения и поиска уникальных значений. Хотя в вашем случае это не принципиально, использовать HashSet или массив.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<String> expectedWords = new HashSet<>();
    expectedWords.add("собака");
    expectedWords.add("кот");
    expectedWords.add("попугай");
    
    System.out.println("Введите значение из массива " + expectedWords);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  userInput = scanner.nextLine();

    while (!expectedWords.contains(userInput)){
        System.out.println("шар, телефон или другой набор букв, не соответствующий набору массива " + expectedWords);
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Вы ввели: " + userInput);
}
```

Вывод

```
Введите значение из массива [попугай, кот, собака]
фффф
шар, телефон или другой набор букв, не соответствующий набору массива [попугай, кот, собака]
попугай
Вы ввели: попугай
```

Comment: о, это то , что мне надо было, спасибо большое

Comment: @kqlqk если помогло, галочка слева от ответа